# Validation and form action dont work together

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with validation on data (E.g the mobile number must contain 10 numbers and numeric) . once everything submitted i've pressed submit button then those data must send to the data base over the php file (access from from action=file.php)

im not sure if i type this form part correctly or not

please help

```html
<form action="patientdetails.php" method="POST" name='registration' onSubmit="return formValidation()"/>





<input type="image" src="Images/submit.png" alt="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: where is formValidation() function defined .please show the code

Comment: You will have a much higher chance at getting an answer if you clearly state your problem. We have no idea if you're having problems with HTML, JavaScript, PHP or whatever.

Comment: agreed.  I would guess the issue would be in your javascript submit function (possible not returning false) but it is hard to guess without the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code like this for form validation :

```
`<script>` <br>
  `function formValidation(){`<br>
  `var myform=document.registration;`<br> 
  `var num=myform.mobilenum.value;`<br>
      `if(num<10){`<br>
         `alert("invalid number");`<br>
         `return false;`<br>
      `}`<br>
     `else{`<br>
        `return true;`<br>
    `}`<br>
`}`


`</script>`




`<form action="patientdetails.php" method="POST" name='registration' onSubmit="return formValidation()"/>`<br>

`<input type="number" name="mobilenum" />`<br>



`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />`
```

Comment: you are welcom.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your form code will cause a problem with validating your input.

Not having any `<input>` elements does make it impossible for anyone to type the mobile number though.

---

There are some things which are wrong, out of date, or low quality…

- There is no `name` attribute for form elements
- Intrinsic event attributes like `onsubmit` are better replaced by JavaScript that uses `addEventListener`
- Image type inputs are designed to provide *server side image maps*, if you just want a graphic to be your submit button you should probably have `<button><img></button>` instead

… but none would cause the problem you are describing.